# Access Forbidden error 403 for git repository on godaddy CD

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, gitversion

1. I have uploaded my website on git
   2.in Cpanel using git version control I have cloned it.
2. I have deployed it and set everything
3. I have followed https://medium.com/@ridbay/how-to-deploy-your-github-repositories-to-cpanel-the-easier-way-16ec6e6cc7ee but I don't have shell access on shared hosting.
4. So I am using public repository to integrate with cpanel.

warning it is showing ( Warning: Your system administrator must enable shell access to allow you to view clone URLS.)

Error (Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.)

However, If I upload file manually and redirects with the domain it works fine but whenever I use git repository to deploy website It does not go well.

Godaddy shared Hosting, Cpanel git version control.
(objective) Continuous Integration by pulling from git repo

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cpanel, you can either use file manager and set permissions to the directory to 755.

[image]

or you can go to advanced, and then open terminal (not sure if you have it though if you don't have shell access in your plan), and navigate to where your directory is, and use chmod 755 dir_name
[image]